# Stellar temperature ~ frequency relationship?

Tags: star, temperature, mathematics, stellar-classification

According to Wikipedia, 76% of all stars are of spectral type M, 12% are of K, 7.5% are of G, etc. (see [this section on Stellar Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification#Spectral_types)). This is very helpful, but is too vague, as the temperature span is too large and irregular to derive an accurate distribution formula for the temperature frequency of a zero-age main sequence star.

Is there such known distribution histogram for zero-age main sequence stars, plotted as $x=T_{eff}$ and $y=\text{percentage of stars}$?

Comment: Have you looked at initial mass functions?

Comment: I doubt that there has been a spectral typing survey on a large volume-limited sample.

Comment: Note also that you are talking about two different things. The temperature distribution of ZAMS stars isn't the same as the T distribution of observed stars and in fact isn't directly observable across the full mass range.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Yes, but it isn't really a distribution. Initial mass functions are exponential functions, and I have no idea on how to convert them into some sort of distribution. But it would be a good start to an answer :)

Comment: ??? Any function can be a distribution function. Just write $df/dN$ on the l.h.s of it???

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Your $df/Dn$ doesn't seem to be working for me. Could you please explain more regarding converting IMFs into distributions?

Comment: @fasterthanlight if I understand your question correctly your looking for the "frequency" in the distribution sense and not in the sense of Hz?

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome Yes.